# Bind nested json to a store and that store to list in sencha touch 2

Tags: list, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I am a newbie when comes to Sencha touch 2.
I am stuck at a point where i am binding a jsonp data with store.
My jsonp data created using newtons json library is as follows:-

```
getjobinfo({"success":true,"method":"GetJobInfo","errormsg":"","csjob":{"jobguid":"1ac1d6bf-80bd-4555-aeba-77e5bdb7b265","jobcode":"ABCDEFGH","jobdescription":"This is the job description. It's a great job. You'll make a lot of money. Hardly any work required.","jobquestions":[{"jobquestionguid":"1ac1d6bf-80bd-4555-aeba-77e5bdb7b266","jobquestiontext":"Describe what you would do if you made a lot of money."},{"jobquestionguid":"1ac1d6bf-80bd-4555-aeba-77e5bdb7b267","jobquestiontext":"Please describe your unique approach to doing nothing and the biggest challenge you've faced doing nothing in other jobs."}]}});
```

The number of questions are dynamic depending on jobcode

i want to get jobcode also and at a different place i want to bind the questions to the list.

but if i try to bind questions i cant access jobcode and viceversa.

I want to use only one store.
Models can be used more than once.

But ho to associate the models that i dont know.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to save your JSON data to an `Ext.data.TreeStore` and display its data through an `Ext.NestedList`. Here's a good example to start: [an example of Sencha Touch nested list and tree store](https://github.com/nelstrom/Sencha-Touch-nested-list-demo)

Note: just look at the **public** folder.